# Clicking a button shows the the url but not taking me to the page I wanted

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, router

I'm using useHistory() for routing different page

I'm using materialui drawer and when clicking to the listitem button I want to go to another page
but its only showing me the url but not taking me to the page

```
 <List>
      
        {sec.map((text, index) => (
              
          <ListItem 
          button
          key={text.title}
          onClick={() => history.push(text.path)}>

          
          <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText
           
            primary={text.title} />
          </ListItem>
      
        
        ))}
        
    
      </List>
```

In app.js I create route :

```
    <BrowserRouter  >
    < SideDrawer />
     <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact  />
      <Route path="/design"  component={Design}  />
      <Route path="/technology"  component={Technology}   />
      </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you handling the click event

Comment: Where is this `List` component being rendered for the `ListItems` to navigate? Can you update your question to include a more comprehensive code example? Can we trace from the `BrowserRouter` all the way to the `ListItem`?

Answer (score 0):

in hooks use this approach

```
import { useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

const yourComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const yourPath = '/your/url/path';
  const openUrl = () =>{  // handler to open url 
     history.push({
          pathname: yourPath
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This shall fix your issue

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


const HomeButton = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleClick = () => {
        // add your path here
        history.push("/home");
    };

    return (
        <List>
            {sec.map((text, index) => (
                <ListItem button key={text.title} onClick={handleClick}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={text.title} />
                </ListItem>
            ))}
        </List>
    );
};
export default HomeButton;
```